How to install mongodb inside lampp folder in linux ubuntu 22?
So I am trying to install mongodb inside lampp folder because my project is using path
/opt/lampp/etc/php.ini  for php.ini instead of  /etc/php/8.2/cli/php.ini
problem is that Class MongoDB\Driver\Manager not found error occurring so when I used php artisan serve the problem is solved I want to run my project without artisan and when i run without artisan it starts using cli /opt/lampp/etc/php.ini instead of /etc/php/8.2/cli/php.ini that is why this error is happening
So I am trying to install mongodb inside lampp folder because my project is using path
/opt/lampp/etc/php.ini  for php.ini instead of  /etc/php/8.2/cli
I have tried sudo pecl install mongodb
which installed mongodb inside /etc/php/8.2/cli instead of /opt/lampp/ folder
also tried many adding php_mongodb.dll file inside /opt/lampp/include/php/ext but it is not working
also tried to run some commands but they did not work
please help
